# Summing a convergent series over the indices of a dense sequence in a small interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $x_n, c_n$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, with $x_n$ dense in $(a,b)$, and $c_n\geq 0$ satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n< \infty$. Define $H_{\delta} = \{n:x<x_n\leq x+\delta\}$. Is it true that $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\sum_{n\in H_{\delta}}c_n=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$?

In other words, can we control the size of the indices of $x_n \in (x,x+\delta]$, so as to make the sum of the $c_n$ with those indices arbitrarily small?

Here's what I've reasoned so far: Because the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ converges, there exists an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $\sum_{n\geq N}c_n <\epsilon$. So if there exists $\delta$ such that all indices of the $x_n$ in $(x,x+\delta]$ are larger than $N_{\epsilon}$, this would ensure $\sum_{n\in H_{\delta}}c_n<\epsilon$, but I'm not sure if this is true (or how to prove/disprove it either way). Intuitively, I would expect that the density of $x_n$ in $(a,b)$ (and hence in $(x,x+\delta]$) would mean that most of the indices would have been exhausted, ensuring only large indices in $(x,x+\delta]$. But you can enumerate a countable set any number of ways, so what's stopping $x_1$ or $x_2$ from being in $(x,x+\delta]$, thus throwing off the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the essential pieces.

Let $\epsilon>0$. There is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n\ge n_\epsilon}c_n<\epsilon$, and there is a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $n\ge n_\epsilon$ whenever $x_n\in(x,x+\delta_\epsilon]$: we need only choose $\delta_\epsilon$ small enough to exclude the finite set $\{x_n:n<n_\epsilon\}$. Thus, $\sum\limits_{n\in H_{\delta_\epsilon}}c_n<\epsilon$, and the desired result follows.

Comment: What enables us to exclude $\{x_n : n<n_{\epsilon}\}$?

Comment: @kieransquared: $\{x_n:n<n_\epsilon\text{ and }x_n>x\}$ is finite, so it has a smallest element, say $x_k$; just choose any positive $\delta_\epsilon<x_k-x$. You can always avoid a finite set.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @kieransquared: You’re welcome.